# Can't see/upload my .env file in cpanel

Tags: laravel-5, cpanel

I can't see my `.env` file in my `cpanel` and i also can't upload `.env` file in my `cpanel`.

What can i do??

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Change the file manager settings to show hidden files. Click on "Settings" to change the preferences.

[image: cpanel file manager settings]

Alternative is to use FTP / SFTP to edit / upload files to your server.